# Creating a residual histogram from discrete 3D data and function

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics

Hi I have this [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d90hgkfnfy0c4rk/data.csv?dl=0) and my function on *Mathematica*:

```
data = Import["/Users/17027/Desktop/data.csv", "CSV"];
fit = (14) (1 - Exp[(-2.61*10^-3) (y)]) + 
40.993272095561764*Exp[(-2.61*10^-3) (y)] + 
Sum[({10 (1.2027906405606206` E^((0.1625723866437297` - 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n) + 
       1.2027906405606206` E^((0.1625723866437297` + 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n) - (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` - 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` - 
            1.545031723755826` I) n] + (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` + 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` + 
            1.545031723755826` I) n] - (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` + 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` - 
            1.5965609298339674` I) n] + (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` - 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` + 
            1.5965609298339674` I) n] + (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` - 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` - 
            1.545031723755826` I) n] - (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` + 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` + 
            1.545031723755826` I) n] + (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` + 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` - 
            1.5965609298339674` I) n] - (0.` + 
          0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` - 
           1.5965609298339674` I) n)
         ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` + 
            1.5965609298339674` I) n] + 
       1/n 1.8942786118762582` Sin[(3.141592653589793` + 
            0.` I) n])}) Exp[-(((1.12*10^-4)*(n)^2*\[Pi]^2)/
       0.2^2 + (2.61*10^-3)) y]*Cos[(n*\[Pi]*x)/0.2], {n, 1, 
  50}];
```

What I wanted do do is create some means of statistical analysis. Thus, is there any way I can create a histogram displaying the residual and their frequency with a specified bin width? It makes sense that residual analysis seems to be the best method in which I can analyse the fit, but I am not to sure how to create it on *Mathematica*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your fit expression: you have the argument of `Sum` wrapped in a list `{}`, which makes for an awkward output format. I don't see any reason for that. I modified your fit function to remove that extraneous list and I'll use the modified version here (see it at the end of the post). I then imported your data and saved it into a variable called `experimental`.

With those, I produced the following estimated data from your fit function (notice that `fit` generates small imaginary components that are probably due to numerical inaccuracies and need to be `Chop`ped away):

```
calcd = Flatten[Chop@Table[{x, y, fit}, {x, 0, 0.2, 0.01}, {y, 0, 50, 1}], 1];

residuals = experimental; 
residuals[[All, 3]] = calcd[[All, 3]] - experimental[[All, 3]];
```

The first assignment to `residuals` is simply a handy way of copying the $x$ and $y$ values from your experimental results. With that in hand, you can create a contour plot of these residuals:

```
ListContourPlot[residuals, ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the amended expression for `fit`:

```
fit = (14) (1 - Exp[(-2.61*10^-3) (y)]) + 
   40.993272095561764*Exp[(-2.61*10^-3) (y)] + 
   Sum[(10 (1.2027906405606206` E^((0.1625723866437297` - 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) + 
         1.2027906405606206` E^((0.1625723866437297` + 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) - (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` - 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` - 
              1.545031723755826` I) n] + (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` + 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` + 
              1.545031723755826` I) n] - (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` + 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` - 
              1.5965609298339674` I) n] + (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((0.1625723866437297` - 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(-0.1625723866437297` + 
              1.5965609298339674` I) n] + (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` - 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` - 
              1.545031723755826` I) n] - (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` + 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` + 
              1.545031723755826` I) n] + (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` + 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` - 
              1.5965609298339674` I) n] - (0.` + 
            0.19143007594988992` I) E^((-0.1625723866437297` - 
               1.5965609298339674` I) n) \
ExpIntegralEi[(0.1625723866437297` + 1.5965609298339674` I) n] + 
         1/n 1.8942786118762582` Sin[(3.141592653589793` + 
              0.` I) n])) Exp[-(((1.12*10^-4)*(n)^2*\[Pi]^2)/
           0.2^2 + (2.61*10^-3)) y]*Cos[(n*\[Pi]*x)/0.2], {n, 1, 50}];
```